# Python: Write to new file line

Tags: python, windows, file

I have been looking around to see if I can find a way to write to a new line in a file every time the user inputs. The basic code is this:

```
while True:
f = open(server,"w")
initchat = str(input("Chat: "))
chat = str((user + " - " + initchat))
f.write(chat)
f.write("\n")
f.close
```

Many of the answers have been to add \n to the string but that only adds a new line after and doesn't allow the new line to be written to. Do I make any sense? Any help would be much appreciated Thanks

Comment: You open the file every `while` iteration -- don't do that, you only have to call `open` once. Moreover, you should find a way to break the loop in order for `close` to be called. In practice it doesn't matter as once the program is terminated and the file closes anyways, but it's something for you to be aware of. You also forgot the `()` in `f.close`. You can refer to my answer for the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
f = open(server,"w")
```

The above will only write 1 line:

You have to use `"a"` for append.

```
f = open(server,"a")
```

BTW: you also have to indent your code after `while:`

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't sure whether append was relevant or not. Thanks

Comment: Using `w` will still turn out right if he ends his lines with a new-line character.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a simple job:

```
with open('file.txt', 'a+') as f:
    initchat = str(input("Chat: "))
    chat = str((user + " - " + initchat))
    f.write(chat+'\n')
```